# Blender console when clicking on UI elements in python console

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

I am working on a blender addon. After working with the addon enabled in the blender window. I start seeing the following bug in the console.

```
RuntimeError: class CONSOLE_OT_banner, function execute: incompatible return value , , Function.result expected a set, not a NoneType
Error: Python: RuntimeError: class CONSOLE_OT_banner, function execute: incompatible return value , , Function.result expected a set, not a NoneType
```

The error goes away if I delete the userpref.blend file and restart blender.
Has anybody else faced this issue or have any suggestions to debug?

Comment: For more complicated issues, it will be helpful to post the code so others can point at the exact location of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the full code I will make an educated guess. Don't forget to add `return{'FINISHED'}` at the bottom of your `execute(self, context)` function, like this:

```
def execute(self, context):
    # do something
    
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

When you don't specify a return value for a function, Python returns `None` by default, so I believe that to be the problem here. Don't forget to check out the Python templates that Blender offers in the Script Editor.

Comment: I am aware of return type and did check  my code after your post. I always `return {"FINISHED"}` at the end of execute function.
I am wondering what happens if my code in the `execute` fails. Would blender automatically `return {"CANCELLED"}` or other valid return value? Or I need to do error checking and return a valid value?

Comment: Well, the error above says specifically that None is being returned instead of a Set (like {'FINISHED'} OR {'CANCELLED'}. Using curly braces {} is how you define a Set in Python, so for some reason you never reach the correct return value.